# MERGE instead of CREATE for apoc.create.relationship()

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

The procedure apoc.create.relationship(n1,RelType,{},n2) behaves accordingly to the CREATE statement. 
If a relationship of type `RelType` already exists between nodes n1 and n2 apoc.create.relationship() will create a duplicate.

Is there an equivalent version of  apoc.create.relationship() that behaves like MERGE?

Answer (score 3):

There is a procedure

`apoc.merge.relationship()`

which takes same parameters as `apoc.create.relationship()` and should do what you need.

It has been mentioned in this [blog post](https://dzone.com/articles/summer-2017-release-of-the-apoc-procedures-library), but it seems to be missing from documentation - see [this issue](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/271).