# Reuse relationship in cypher with merge

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

With the following graph:

```
(Boxer)-[:STARTS]->(Round)-[:CONTINUES]->(Round)-[:CONTINUES]->(Round)-[:CONTINUES]->(Round)
```

I want to remove a (Round) in the linked list.

I got a successful result by doing this:

```
MATCH (round:Round {uuid: $round.uuid})
MATCH (prevRound)-[:CONTINUES]->(round)-[:CONTINUES]->(nextRound)
DETACH DELETE round
MERGE (prevRound)-[:CONTINUES]->(round)
```

But this will work for any Round except the first one, because it has a STARTS a relationship. So I tried this:

```
MATCH (round:Round {uuid: $round.uuid})
MATCH (prevRound)-[prevRel:CONTINUES|STARTS]->(round)-[nextRel:CONTINUES]->(nextRound)
DETACH DELETE round
MERGE (prevRound)-[prevRel]->(round)
```

But I get this error:

```
Neo4jError: Variable `prevRel` already declared 
MERGE (prevRound)-[prevRel]->(nextRound)"
```

Comment: Note that you're also trying to reuse the `round` variable...which is the node you just deleted! I think you mean to use `nextRound` for the node at the end instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a identifier to dynamically create a relationship in cypher.

In your statement the planner thinks that you are trying to use `prevRel` as an identifier in your `MERGE` but it is already used in the `MATCH` above.

Fortunately there is a solution for this using APOC. The `apoc.merge.relationship` procudeure can be used to create a new relationship type that is the same as the one you removed when you removed the round.

```
MATCH (round:Round {uuid: $round.uuid})
MATCH (prevRound)-[prevRel:CONTINUES|STARTS]->(round)-[nextRel:CONTINUES]->(nextRound)
DETACH DELETE round
WITH prevRound, prevRel, nextRound
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(prevRound, type(prevRel), {}, {}, nextRound) YIELD rel
RETURN prevRound, rel, nextRound
```

Comment: Might need to use `nextRound` instead for the node at the other end, since `round` was just deleted.

Comment: I'm getting an error: WITH is required between DELETE and CALL

Comment: Sorry about that. Lack of attention to detail on my part. I updated it.

Comment: Thanks, it was still not working, it took me a while to figure out I had to add a YIELD and RETURN. I found this thread that explains apoc.merge.relationship is missing from the doc: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52273703/merge-instead-of-create-for-apoc-create-relationship
Anyway, please update your answer by adding "YIELD rel RETURN" at the end.

Comment: roger that - glad you got it sorted